# How to remove parameters from a url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

wasted the whole day trying to hide the url parameters from a url using php but failed

sports%20betting/index.php?type=matchresult

i want to remove type=matchresult from the link could somebody help me ??

Comment: Thanks man let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule "^sports betting/index\.php$" $0? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: +1, that looks efficient—didn't know about using quotes when there is a space, and never thought of using `$0`, nice! :)